# How to solve equation when the unknown cannot be placed separately

Tags: python-2.7, equation

Could any one tell me how to solve this kind of equations for one unknown which could not be separated from the other variables!

```
L_1=(D/f)*(((1- M**2)/(gamma*M**2))+((1+gamma)/(2*gamma))*math.log(((1+gamma)*M**2)/(2+(M**2*(gamma-1)))))
```

I want to find the M value when all other value is known to me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially trying to find the root of this function. In general terms, you could write:

f(M) - L_1 = 0

With this knowledge, create a function for your equation:

```
import numpy as np
def myfunc(M, L_1, D, gamma, f):
    return (D/f)*(((1- M**2)/(gamma*M**2))+((1+gamma)/(2*gamma))*np.log(((1+gamma)*M**2)/(2+(M**2*(gamma-1))))) - L_1
```

You can then use the [brentq function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq) from scipy.optimize to find the root of M. I'm using a few sample values here for L_1 (=1.0), D (=0.5), gamma (=0.05) and f (=0.01) respectively

```
from scipy.optimization import brentq
root = brentq(myfunc, a=0.01, b=1.0, args=(1.0, 0.5, 0.05, 0.01))
print(root)
```

Tried it with Python 3, should work.

Comment: Note that I recommend using numpy instead of math, it's more efficient